# Rename .gz files according to names in separate txt-file

Tags: linux, rename, gzip

I want to rename .gz files according to names in separate txt-file.
I have a map with .gz files with the names:

```
trooper10.gz
trooper11.gz 
trooper12.gz
etc.
```

and I have a separate txt-file with the wanted name(s) in in the first column and the .gz-names in the other column (tab-separated).

```
B25    trooper10
C76    trooper11
A87_2    trooper12
```

So the files should be renamed like this

```
B25.gz
C76.gz
A87_2.gz
```

I tried

```
for i in *.gz; do
line=$(grep -x -m 1 -- "${i}" /path_to_txtfile/list_names.txt)
```

But im not sure how to grep the corresponding column in the txt-file. Since there is many gz-files I want to ask if there is any way to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you just start by reading the file instead of getting the gz files from the file system:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r newName oldName; do
    mv -- "$oldName".gz "$newName.gz"
done < names_file
```

Comment: When I tried this, I receive the following error:

mv: cannot stat 'trooper10'$'\r''.gz': No such file or directory

Comment: @Yoshi that's because you seem to be using Windows and not Linux? Your file is a Windows text file with Windows line endings. Fix the file with `dos2unix names_file` or `sed -i 's/\r//' names_file` and try again.

Comment: The `\r` suggests that your `names_file`  came from a windows machine.  try converting it with `fromdos` (or `tr -d $'\r'` if you don't have fromdos or similar)

Answer (score 5):

Could that not just be:

```
<list_names.txt awk -F'\t' '{printf "%s.gz\0%s.gz\0", $2, $1}' | xargs -r0n2 mv --
```

Or more efficiently:

```
perl -F'\t' -lae 'rename "$F[1].gz", $"F[0].gz" or warn "$F[1].gz: $!\n"' list_names.txt
```

Comment: No need `-a` with `-F` (implicit)

Comment: Thanks @Gilles, I wasn't aware that. May be better to keep it though to make it clear that the `a`wk mode is being used and would remain in use even if we removed the `-F` to revert to using the default separator. I'm undecided.

Comment: You can choose `-F`  or `-a`, both should works. But using both at the same time is redundant. To be close like awk, you can keep `-F` and remove `-a` that is not related to awk unlike `-F`